# Resgatar valores de um item no modal para atualiza-lo no banco

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-3, formulário

Tenho alguns itens retornado do banco que é listado em uma tabela. Para adicionar um item, chamo um *modal* no qual preencho os campos salvando-os no banco. No entanto, caso o preenchimento deste campo esteja errado, preciso fazer a edição do mesmo. A questão é, como faço para resgatar os valores referente a cada linha clicando no `edit` para fazer um *update* no banco?

Veja o código abaixo como exemplo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th width="6%">Data</th>
         <th width="40%">Descrição</th>
         <th width="10%">Ação</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td rel="date">27/10/2016</td>
         <td rel="description">Febre amarela</td>
         <td rel="action">
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/51/show/" data-target="#myModal">Edit</a>
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#add">Delete</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
         <td rel="date">27/10/2016</td>
         <td rel="description">Gripe suína</td>
         <td rel="action">
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/51/show/" data-target="#myModal">Edit</a>
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#add">Delete</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <form>
           Descrição: <input type="text"/>
           </form>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Obs.: O botão delete é só fictício.

**EDIT**

Estou utilizando o PHP como *back end* para busca desses dados no banco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após a tabela carregada, você pode incluir uma classe nos botões *editar* para "ouvir" o evento *click*. Então para obter valores da linha, você usar subir dois níveis usando [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), e pesquisar pela descrição daquela linha. Por fim, incluir o valor de *description* no input para edição.

Esse trecho:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('td[rel="description"]').html();
```

Ele vai subir para a linha, visto que o link está aqui:

```
> TR
  > TD
    > A
```

Quando voltar para linha, irá pesquisar usando `find('td[rel="description"]')` pelo elemento que desejas.

### Seu Exemplo:

```js
$(".editar").click(function() {
  var descricao = $(this).parent().parent().find('td[rel="description"]').html();
  $("#descricao").val(descricao);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="6%">Data</th>
      <th width="40%">Descrição</th>
      <th width="10%">Ação</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rel="date">27/10/2016</td>
      <td rel="description">Febre amarela</td>
      <td rel="action">
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/51/show/" data-target="#myModal" class="editar">Edit</a>
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#add">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rel="date">27/10/2016</td>
      <td rel="description">Gripe suína</td>
      <td rel="action">
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/51/show/" data-target="#myModal" class="editar">Edit</a>
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#add">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          Descrição:
          <input id="descricao" type="text" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Caso tenha outros campos, seria apenas replicar alterando o rel?

Comment: Por exemplo, se abrir o mesmo modal tanto para editar tanto para adicionar, como faço para pegar o valor do botão que estou clicando (se é edit ou add)?

Comment: Sim, para outros campos, só mudar o seletor e salvar em variáveis diferentes. No seu exemplo está descricao, mas pode ser *n* variáveis..

Comment: Para ver qual botão está clicando pode fazer assim: `$(this).html() == 'Edit')`. Colocando dentro de um `if` para verificar se é *edit* ou *add*. `$(this)` é o seletor que obtém o objeto do elemento que foi o target @AckLay

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida. Como faço para pegar o em vez do html, pegar o value?

Comment: O value geralmente é para inputs, usando .val().  Para outros elementos, se não me engano .attr('value') ou .prop('value')

Comment: funcionou com attr. valeu. abs.

Comment: Seria mais fácil utilizar `.parents('tr')` ao invés do `.parent().parent()`. Isso fará subir para o parente `tr`, ou pode usar o `.closest('tr')`.  Ambos funcionam, de qualquer forma. ;)

Comment: Não conhecia o método `parents` @Inkeliz, aprendi mais uma =] muito obrigado!